# All the functionalities of plotly using ggplot and shiny to create a very interactive plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, interactive

I've been looking at many resources and it's very hard to find a reproducible example with all the functionalities of an interactive plot. I would really like a plot in a shiny app to have these functionalities which are similar to the options offered in `plotly()`:

1. Have a zoom option when a region is brushed and double clicked
2. Has an option to remove points corresponding to its legends
3. Displays the point's x and y value when hovered on top

I couldn't find all these functionalities in the same code. I personally wish that every scatterplot should have these functions if they are used in a shiny app. Due to this feature in `ggplot()` many people prefer `plotly()`. After seeing the answer to this question I hope everyone will prefer using `ggplot()` alonf with `shiny`

I've created zoom feature, help me with the second and third feature i.e option to remove points corresponding to group 1 when group 1 is clicked in the legends and display point's x and y-axis value when the mouse is hovered above it. Thanks!!!

**Here are sample Data and code to get started.**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(shiny)
ui=fluidPage(uiOutput("plot"))
server = function(input, output) {
  #creating a range variable for zooming 
  ranges <<- reactiveValues(x = NULL, y = NULL)
  #Creating sample Data
  Data=data.frame(Group=c("Group 2","Group 1","Group 3","Group 2","Group 5","Group 4","Group 6",
                          "Group 7","Group 4","Group 3","Group 1","Group 5","Group 6","Group 7",
                          "Group 2","Group 4","Group 6","Group 7","Group 3","Group 1"),
                  Fruit=c("apple","apple","apple","mango","apple","apple","apple","apple","mango","mango",
                          "mango","mango","mango","mango","orange","orange","orange","orange","orange",
                          "orange"),
                  Percentage=c(68.46846847,77.35849057,72.72727273,26.12612613,76.31578947,62.79069767,
                               71.05263158,69.23076923,30.23255814,25,20.75471698,23.68421053,23.68421053,
                               23.07692308,5.405405405,6.976744186,5.263157895,7.692307692,2.272727273,
                               1.886792453))
  #Creating the plor function
  output$graph<-renderPlot({
    ggplot(Data,aes(y=reorder(Fruit,Percentage),x=Percentage,
                    color=Group,
                    label=paste0(round(Percentage),"%")))+
      geom_point(size=4)+
      scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,100))+
      theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_line(color="gray90",size = 0.7),
            panel.background=element_blank(),
            strip.background=element_blank(),
            panel.border=element_rect(color="black",fill=NA,size=1))+
      labs(y="",x="% of people",color="")+
      # geom_text_repel(direction="y",nudge_y = 0.2, point.padding = 0.1, box.padding = 0.1)+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = ranges$x, ylim = ranges$y, expand = T)
  })
  #Rendering the plot with the brush parameter
  output$plot=renderUI(
    plotOutput("graph",dblclick = "plot1_dblclick",brush = brushOpts(id = "plot1_brush",resetOnNew = TRUE),height=450,width=900)  
  )
  #To observe and change the limits of the graph (zooming)
  observeEvent(input$plot1_dblclick, {
    brush <- input$plot1_brush
    if (!is.null(brush)) {
      ranges$x <- c(brush$xmin, brush$xmax)
      ranges$y <- c(brush$ymin, brush$ymax)

    } else {
      ranges$x <- NULL
      ranges$y <- NULL
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: If clicking the legend is not possible, It would also be great if the points are removed when they are single-clicked in the main panel.

Comment: Do you know about ggplotly()?